# Bordercrossing point (Grenzübergang) on Austrian national visa D application form? Entry point into Austria or Entry point to Schengen

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, schengen-visas, austria

I currently reside in India and hold an Indian passport. I am applying for Austrian national visa (visa D). In the [application form](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b9309be4b06e38ad5da1ca/t/5c33b8e2758d46c9dec8aaef/1546893538933/Antragsformular_Visum_D.pdf), I am supposed to specify the bordercrossing point (Grenzübergang) (see the third row from the end on the 1st page in the linked form). I would like to know if the expected answer is the entry point into Austria or the entry point into the Schengen area.

To be particular, my travel plan from Mumbai to Vienna includes a short (~ 3.5 hours) layover in Frankfurt, Germany from where I will take a connecting flight to Vienna. So while my entry point into Austria will be Vienna, my entry point into the Schengen area will be Frankfurt. So which one of those cities should be mentioned as the bordercrossing point(Grenzübergang) in the visa application form?.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Do you have a link to this application form?

Comment: @MarkJohnson, you could find the form [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b9309be4b06e38ad5da1ca/t/5c33b8e2758d46c9dec8aaef/1546893538933/Antragsformular_Visum_D.pdf). The bordercrossing point(Grenzübergang) is asked towards the bottom of the first page (third row from the end, second column)

Comment: I could find no information on this topic. If you are sure of your route write: **Frankfurt/Vienna**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, thanks. I am sure of the route as I have already booked the flight tickets. If I don't find out any concrete information about this topic, I am indeed going to write Frankfurt/Vienna. Although I wonder if that conveys uncertainty of plans.

Comment: Maybe then **Frankfurt->Vienna**. But I doubt it is really important since a D-Visa normally allows you to enter at any border point.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, thanks, that answer looks unambiguous. Do you think it might be beneficial if I explain the travel plans in the cover letter and attach a photocopy of flight tickets?

Comment: As an explanation why the field was left blank, plus the information you were not sure which one was being ask for will cause no harm.